# Is it haram to accidentally "masturbate"?

Tags: sex, masturbation

So my problem is that sometimes out of nowhere I will hold my penis (not rubbing, just a hold) but then my penis will start ejaculating! I will try to hold it in but lately it fails. It makes me feel miserable sometimes. Is it haram?

Comment: Since we have so many of these types of questions, I will give an answer in 10 words, "Sin. Fast and lower gaze. Break habit. Allah is forgiving

Answer (score 1):

Why would you hold it? It is haram to waste your sperm in such way. You must try your best not to do this. Don't hold it for long time. If you know why it happens then you have to find a solution too. It will fall under the category of masturbation if you intentionally hold it for long time and you ejaculate. Stop doing this.